# PSR-2 if-statement — what is allowed?

Tags: php, if-statement, psr-2

Can I use **if**-statement like:

```
if(true) return $value;
```

Or must use always with braces:

```
if(true) {
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Section 5.1 of the [psr-2 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) explicitly states that:

> An if structure looks like the following. Note the placement of parentheses, spaces, and braces; and that else and elseif are on the same line as the closing brace from the earlier body.

```
<?php
if ($expr1) {
    // if body
} elseif ($expr2) {
    // elseif body
} else {
    // else body;
}
```

So, according to psr-2, you **must** use braces for an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks! I found this in 5 section (one line before): `The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. This standardizes how the structures look, and reduces the likelihood of introducing errors as new lines get added to the body.` I do not know how I missed it.